# That helps to achieve

Tags: grammar, logic

Is this sentence correct both grammatically and logically speaking?
The sentence is part of an email to a teacher and the context is a school play.

Dear Mr Lyons,

Thank you for email.

In my view, performing this play is a fantastic idea, and I can't wait to get started. For this performance, I'm willing to do anything **that helps to achieve**  an amazing play. In particular, if that's fine with you, I can offer to make some costumes.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really idiomatic to say "to achieve an amazing play".

One achieves a result, an outcome, a score, success, happiness - abstract things.

A better choice might be "helps to create" or "helps to produce".

A side note: "I'm willing to do anything" is a pretty dangerous phrase that, to a native English speaker, raises suggestions of improper behaviour. A more natural and neutral phrase would be "I'm keen to help in any way possible".